# Backbone Boilerplate (BB) within an express server

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm using [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/) of Tim Branyen. This great project use "bbb" commands to develop.

"bbb server" command starts an static server, and everything works great for the front-end development.

But because I'm developing front-end and back-end at once, I need to integrate backbone boilerplate within my nodejs/express server (where I have the back-end code). I need all in the same server.

So, what I did was put backbone boilerplate project into a folder "/public" and I start the server conventionally "node server.js".

In this way I lose all the functionality of the "bbb server" command, such as real-time compile style.

What would be the best way to handle this?
and avoid start 2 servers (front/back) for a same project.

Thanks in advance!
(and sorry my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to implement those functionnalty on your own server.

`bbb server` simply start a basic express server with some middleware managing assets (compiling styles, etc). You just need to do the same.

Checkout [`grunt-bbb-server`](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb-server/blob/master/tasks/server.js) to see how it is implemented, and just replicate it on your own server.